# Deserialize LocalDateTime usin Gson is not working

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I need to convert a string to a an object using Gson :

```
gson.fromJson("{\"message\":\"any msg.\",\"individual\":{\"id\":100,\"citizenshipList\":[{\"date\":[2018,10,15,16,29,36,402000000]}]}}", Response.class)
```

where

```
public class Response {
    private String message;
    private Individual individual;
}

public class Individual {
 private Integer id;
 private List<Citizenship> citizenshipList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Citizenship {

  @DateTimeFormat(pattern="d::MMM::uuuu HH::mm::ss")
  LocalDateTime date;

}
```

I m getting this error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was
>   BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 122 path
>   $.individual.citizenshipList[0].date

I have tried also a modified Gson :

```
Gson gson1 = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, new JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime>() {
                @Override
                public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
                    JsonObject jo = json.getAsJsonObject();
                    return LocalDateTime.of(jo.get("year").getAsInt(),
                            jo.get("monthValue").getAsInt(),
                            jo.get("dayOfMonth").getAsInt(),
                            jo.get("hour").getAsInt(),
                            jo.get("minute").getAsInt(),
                            jo.get("second").getAsInt(),
                            jo.get("nano").getAsInt());
                }
            }).create();
```

but this gives me this error :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object:
>   [2018,10,15,16,29,36,402000000]

Comment: Why the date is split into an array? And not being passed as `2018-10-15...`?

Comment: Try using a `JsonArray` instead of `JsonObject`.

Comment: it is not me that Doing that it is Mockito mvc with MockHttpServletResponse .getContentAsString() and the attribute is using localdatetime

Answer (score 2):

Both of the errors you have posted say what the problem is:

> Not a JSON Object: [2018,10,15,16,29,36,402000000]
>
> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

`[2018,10,15,16,29,36,402000000]` is a JSON *array* and GSON expects a JSON *object*, e.g.: `{}`.

One way to solve it is to modify your `JsonDeserializer` to use `JsonArray` instead of `JsonObject`:

```
Gson gson1 = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, new JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime>() {
                @Override
                public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
                    JsonArray array = json.getJSONArray("date");
                    return LocalDateTime.of(
                                            // Set all values here from
                                            // `array` variable
                                            );
                }
            }).create();
```

Comment: thanks, yes it is the case .. but  more general it is because in my unit mockito is using Jackson to serialise the object and jackson serialize it using jsonarray